# Prefix matching search in multiple words in dart

Tags: dart

Let's consider a list:

```
List<String> recipeNamesList = [
  'Burger',
  'French Fries',
  'Pizza',
  'Bengali Lamb Curry',
  'Chingri Malai Curry',
];
```

What my search needs to do:

1. Only match using prefix so if the user types in `ger` it shouldn't return burger. It should return burger only when someone types in `bur`.
2. If someone types in `Bengali Curry` it should return `Bengali Lamb Curry`.
3. If someone types in `Curry` it should return `Bengali Lamb Curry` & 'Chingri Malai Curry',

What I've tried so far(got help from another question I asked):

```
  Future<List<String>> getSuggestions(String search) async {
    List<String> results = [];
    List<String> searchSplit = search.toLowerCase().split(" "); // split the search query
    
    for (int i = 0; i < searchSplit.length; i++) { // iterate over search query
      for (int j = 0; j < recipeNamesList.length; j++) { // iterate over the recipe names list
        List<String> recipeNamesListSplit = recipeNamesList[j].split(" "); // split the recipe names 
        for (int k = 0; k < recipeNamesListSplit.length; k++) { // iterate over the list of splitted name
          if (recipeNamesListSplit[k]
              .toLowerCase()
              .startsWith(searchSplit[i])) { // convert to lower case and check if the query is present in splitted name
            results.add(recipeNamesList[j]); // if contains == true add to results
          }
        }
      }
    }

    // Avoid repeated values
    results = results.toSet().toList();
    return results;
  }
```

Issues with code:

1. If I provide a space(anywhere in text field) it loads everything.
2. If I type `Bengali Curry` it returns both `Bengali Lamb Curry` & 'Chingri Malai Curry'.

Can any one point out what I did wrong in this code?

N.B: any pointer for an even optimized code will be appreciated. Although it's not a must right now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 1. If I provide a space(anywhere in text field) it loads everything.

I don't observe that when trying your code.  It will happen if your search string contains *multiple consecutive spaces* because `String.split` unfortunately does not collapse consecutive instances of the search pattern.  For example, `'fooxxxbar'.split('x')` will return `['foo', '', '', 'bar']`.  You later check if any of the tokens from `recipeNamesList` start with any of those elements, but `''.startsWith(string)` is always true.

An easy way to fix that is to essentially collapse whitespace yourself by making the search pattern match one-or-more whitespace characters.  That is, replace `string.split(' ')` with `string.split(RegExp(r'\s+'))`.

Another easy way to fix it is to just `continue` if encountering an empty token to ignore it.

> 2. If I type Bengali Curry it returns both Bengali Lamb Curry & 'Chingri Malai Curry'.

Your current algorithm always adds the `results` list whenever it finds *any* match.  It searches for `'bengali'`, finds one item, adds it to `results`, searches for `'curry'`, finds both of those results, and adds both of them.

Instead of iterating over search tokens in the outer loop and iterating over the `recipeNamesList` tokens in the inner loop, it would make more sense to iterate over `recipeNamesList`, and on each iteration, check if *all* of the search tokens match the tokens of the search string.  If so, then add that recipe name to the list of results<sup>1</sup>.  That also would prevent the same recipe name from being added multiple times without needing to use a `Set`.

<sup>1</sup> Or if you want fuzzier matching, record a score for each recipe name (e.g. the number of search tokens that were matched), sort the results by the scores, and discard any below a certain threshold.